# Why does ggsave() output a different font from what I'm specifying and is shown in the RStudio viewer?

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts, ggsave

I downloaded the latest RStudio the other day and I've started running into problems with the font when I use `ggsave()`.

I specify the font as I always have (after loading fonts with `extrafont`, and it shows up correctly in the RStudio viewer), but when I save the output through `ggsave()` it appears to give me a different style of that font family (Myriad Pro). This didn't happen before downloading the latest RStudio.

Here's a example:

```
library(tidyverse)
extrafont::loadfonts(device = "win")

n <- 6
dat <- data.frame(id=1:n, 
                  date=seq.Date(as.Date("2020-12-26"), as.Date("2020-12-31"), "day"),
                  group=rep(LETTERS[1:2], n/2),
                  age=sample(18:30, n, replace=TRUE),
                  type=factor(paste("type", 1:n)),
                  x=rnorm(n))

dat %>%
  ggplot(aes(age, x)) +
  labs(x = "Here is a label for my x axis",
       y = "Here is a slightly different one for my y axis",
       title = "This is an example title") +
  theme(text = element_text(family = "Myriad Pro"))

ggsave("test_output.png")
```

In RStudio, I'm seeing this (font is correct):

[image: rstudio_viewer]

but `ggsave()` is giving me this (font is incorrect) and I have no idea why:

[image: ggsave_output]

I'm using the same code that's worked previously, but it seems like I'm now getting the condensed style of Myriad Pro?

Does anyone have any ideas about what might be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: I'll also add that when I use gtsave() to save my {gt} tables, the font works fine?

Comment: What version of R, RStudio, and extrafont are you using?

Comment: If anyone comes to this with the same issue, it seems that the `ragg` package (and associated graphics device) was causing the unexpected font behaviour. Uninstalling {ragg} by using `installr::uninstall.packages("ragg")` worked for me. 

I'm not sure why it worked, or why `ragg` doesn't give me the font I'm after. I've since read about the many advantages of the `ragg` graphics device, so I might keep experimenting to try and find a way to get my desired output with `ragg`. I'm interested to hear if anyone thinks they know why it might be happening?